# Fluid dynamics for order book depth modelling

Tags: time-series, equities, data, quant-trading-strategies, research

Would someone be able to give me an idea what type of fluid dynamics I could look at for modelling the order book? My background is more signals-related maths (correlation, covariance, fourier etc).

I am interested in modelling the order book based upon the buy/sell pressure within the order book depth.

Comment: I've never heard of using fluid dynamics used to model the order book. Did you see this mentioned some place?

Comment: a good start is the Markovian jump-diffusion process and that's only for the limit order book ;)